# Set Font that contains space in its name

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I try to set text field font in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC:

```
var f = this.getField("mytext");
f.textFont = "Microsoft Sans Serif";
```

but it throw exception

```
InvalidSetError: Set not possible, invalid or unknown.
Field.textFont:1:Console undefined:Exec
```

I think it is because spaces in font name. it doesn't have problem with single word fonts.
how can I use system font with space in its name?

(os: Windows 8.1)

Comment: Remove the spaces is the usual convention.

Comment: thanks, it worked. sorry i can't upvote.